# c# asp.net Callback does not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, callback

I am developing a software which uses 2-way WCF (httpDualBinding)
My Client is Asp.Net app. When the server call a function from the client, i can see that the function receives the control, but its intructiuons does not apply on my webpage.

Here is my client code:

```
public static CallbackClientHandler callback;
public static InstanceContext context;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Callback"] == null)
    {
        callback = new CallbackClientHandler();
        callback.OnPelakDetected += Callback_OnPelakDetected;
        context = new InstanceContext(callback);
        Session["Callback"] = callback;
    }
}

private string Callback_OnPelakDetected()
{
    Button1.Text = "some caption";
    return "123";
}
```

the 'Callback_OnPelakDetected' method returns "123" correctly, but thr caption of Button1 dos not change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net you cannot simply change properties of controls any time after the page has finished loading.

You need to have something in the browser (JavaScript) which allows to return control to the server to update information on the page.